# Unable to get username and password from angularjs to spring security

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

Developing app on Angular.js with Spring Security. I am not able to send the username and password from UI to spring security. Getting null pointer exception. After debugging found that, username is null. Searched a lot on google but not able to fix it. When I click on login button, the debugger takes me to the userdetailserviceimpl.java class and found that username is null. In normal case if I am using spring security login form, if I submit the form with wrong credentials username is not coming null but with ajax call from UI it is coming null.

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthBuilder(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    builder.userDetailsService(userDetailServiceImpl);          
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


http
.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/login.html").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorisedHandler)
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDenied)
        .and()
.formLogin()
.loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
    .successHandler(authSuccess)
    .usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccess).permitAll()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable();      

}
```

UserDetailServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDao loginDao;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserInfo userInfo = loginDao.loadUserByUsername(username);
        System.out.println(userInfo.getUserName() + "" + userInfo.getRole());
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userInfo.getRole());
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)new User(userInfo.getUserName(), userInfo.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

login.controller.js

```
var vm = this;
    vm.credentials = {};

    vm.login = function(){
        var config = {
                params: {
                 username: vm.credentials.username,
                 password: vm.credentials.password,
                }
               };
        loginService.login(config);
    };
```

login.service.js

```
this.login = function(config){
    return ajaxService.login("../authenticate",config);
};
```

common ajax service

```
this.login = function (url, dataObj) {

        var res = $http({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: dataObj,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
              }
        });

        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
        return res;
    };
```

login.html

```
<div ng-controller='LoginController as lc'>

<form>
    <div class="form-group"
         ng-class="{'has-error is-focused' : authenticationError}">
        <input id="login" ng-model="lc.credentials.username" type="text" class="form-control"
               required="required" placeholder="login"/>
        <span ng-show="authenticationError" class="help-block">
            Please check your credentials and try again.
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="password" ng-model="lc.credentials.password" type="password" class="form-control"
               required="required" placeholder="password"/>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rememberMe"/><span> Remember me</span>

    <button ng-click="lc.login()" >Login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Update for stack trace

```
Nov 22, 2016 12:47:16 AM org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter doFilter
SEVERE: An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.er4u.core.login.service.impl.UserDetailServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailServiceImpl.java:30)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: @Mr.7 setting username and password in html page in credentials model

Comment: I guess this is due to extra keys in dataObj sent in the request. Can you try removing `params:` from request object and directly add `username` and `password` in the object?

Comment: @HarryJoy - thanks for the suggestion but I already applied this and its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue by changing

```
var config = {
                params: {
                 username: vm.credentials.username,
                 password: vm.credentials.password,
                }
               };
```

to

```
vm.user = "username="+vm.credentials.username+"&password="+vm.credentials.password;
```

Thanks everyone for helping. Hope this answer will help others in future. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wrapper object, while Spring is just expecting the `username` and `password` in an object. Change 
`var config = { params: { username: vm.credentials.username, password: vm.credentials.password}};` to `var config = {username: vm.credentials.username, password: vm.credentials.password`. Also, there is a tutorial that shows you exactly how to do this with simplicity:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Comment: I have also tried this but getting username null in userdetailserviceimpl.java class

Comment: try to use chrome debugger and see the information sent to the server.

Comment: @HaimRaman - Yes, I debug it using chrome debugger and information is sending perfectly fine.

Comment: @VaibhavDalela Okay, so the username exists in the payload object, but you're getting a null pointer exception server-side? Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @J.West - added stack trace.

Comment: @VaibhavDalela I don't think your edit got saved, I'm not seeing it. One thing I thought of though, have you actually loaded a user into your database to login with? For example, if you were not registered for your app, and you ran the method `loginDao.loadUserByUsername(username);`, then you would get the null pointer exception.

Comment: @J.West - Now I have saved it successfully and about database, I was previously able to login it with spring security login form. But the issue is different. The parameter passed in public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) method in userdetailserviceimpl.java is coming null. It should catch the username which I am sending from UI side.

Comment: @VaibhavDalela try removing `formLogin()` from your security config. This is expecting a non-REST form-submit, so this could be the issue.

Comment: @J.West - Tried but it is also not woking. I am following this tutorial to implement spring security with angularjs - https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/secure-angularjs-application-with-spring-security/ .Tried everything but nothing is working, dont know I am doing wrong. Really frustrated now

Comment: Try using the tutorial I posted in my answer. It uses httpBasic and base-64 encoded authorization, so a little different than what you are doing. Very straightforward and I was able to easily get it working my first try when I started working with Spring + Ang.

Comment: @J.West - This tutorial is using spring boot, which I dont want to use in my app. Yes, the concept is very clear in the tutorial but I do not want to use spring boot.